# One canvas , multiple layered content

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have built a banner with multiple canvas (position: absolute, different z-idexes) BUT... but I'd liek to re-create teh whole thing with ONE canvas only and it proves to be a problem. the banner's animation is quite complex so here is a brief question taht will help me to understand how it works.

I'd like to "cut" a hole in that black rectangle so the red one becomes visible

Here is the code:

```
    red.beginPath(); 
    red.fillStyle = '#af0000';  
    red.fillRect(33, 33, 200, 60); // drawing red rectangle
    red.closePath();

    red.beginPath();
    red.fillStyle = '#000'; 
    red.fillRect(77, 66, 120, 60); // drawing black one
    red.clearRect(110, 80, 20, 20); // cutting 20X20 pixels rectangle
    red.closePath();
```

I know why both rectangles are affected. This is just to illustrate what I'd like to achieve. I could make it with two canvas  - to draw the red rectangle on one and the black on another, and cut the black one - but I'd like to get it with ONE canvas only. 
Also - I know I could re-draw that red part but  doubt that's a wise solution.

Here is Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hej11px9/

Thanks in advance!

I know this is quite amateurish question but...anyway - tried to find teh solution with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not that easy : to draw with a hole, you must clip **out** a part of your rect, when clipping is meant to clip in.
But there's a solution to clip out a rect : clip in the whole canvas, then substract the inner rect going counter clockwise.

I also had your code 'data driven', so it's easier to make a change.

http://jsfiddle.net/casemate/hej11px9/1/

[image]

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var redRect = {
    x: 33,
    y: 33,
    width: 200,
    height: 60,
    color: '#af0000'
};
var blackRect = {
    x: 77,
    y: 66,
    width: 120,
    height: 60,
    color: '#000'
};
var blackRectHole = {
    x: 110,
    y: 80,
    width: 20,
    height: 20
};
var cvRect = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: canvas.width,
    height: canvas.height
};


function drawRect(rect) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = rect.color;
    ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawRectClipped(rect, clipRect) {
    ctx.save();
   clipOut(clipRect);
    drawRect(rect);
    ctx.restore();
}

function clipOut(clipRect) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    rectPath(cvRect);
    ctx.lineTo(clipRect.x, clipRect.y);
    rectPath_ccw(clipRect);
    ctx.clip();    
}

function rectPath(rect) {
    ctx.moveTo(rect.x, rect.y);
    ctx.lineTo(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y);
    ctx.lineTo(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height);
    ctx.lineTo(rect.x, rect.y + rect.height);
    ctx.lineTo(rect.x, rect.y);
}

function rectPath_ccw(rect) {
    ctx.moveTo(rect.x, rect.y);
    ctx.lineTo(rect.x, rect.y + rect.height);
    ctx.lineTo(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height);
    ctx.lineTo(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y);
    ctx.lineTo(rect.x, rect.y);
}

drawRect(redRect);
drawRectClipped(blackRect, blackRectHole);
```

Comment: Thanks a million, Alchemist, sire! Gotta analyze the code in an hour.